# Npm randomly freezes

Tags: npm, npm-install

I have been using npm for a react native project, and among other issues (like npm deleting all of my dependencies when I try to install a package), it *constantly* freezes. Here is a powershell screenshot:
[image]

And similar output to this appears on nearly all of my install attempts. It hangs on this idealTree : timing no matter what package, output parameters, etc. Occasionally after many attempts of installing, cancelling, restarting the terminal, etc, it will allow an installation to succeed (and then, of course, it deletes my packages). I have sometimes just given up with npm installs and used yarn when available, so the packages may have gotten mixed (although this was happening before). How can I solve this issue?

--
Verbose output doesn't help clarify the issue, it just prints hundreds of lines of timing messages and then still freezes.
[image]

Comment: I have got this in the past, It turned out to be a network problem somehow, I switched to mobile hotspot and everything worked

Comment: Unfortunately did not help.. I think I am just going to use yarn for everything

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a problem with the network connectivity as mentioned [here](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/7254#issuecomment-905767204).

Try to do the following steps:

```
sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
sudo bash -c 'echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf'
sudo bash -c 'echo "[network]" > /etc/wsl.conf'
sudo bash -c 'echo "generateResolvConf = false" >> /etc/wsl.conf'
sudo chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf
```

Then restart - npm install should run smooth again